# Form Submission with admin_url() Set as Action

Tags: forms, wordpress

I have the following form as part of a Wordpress plugin:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url(); ?>">
    Area Name: <input type="text" name="new_area_name" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('New Area Name', 'libhours'); ?>" required><br>
    URL (optional): <input type="text" name="new_area_url" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('http://emich.edu/library/newplace', 'libhours'); ?>"><br>
    Note (optional): <textarea rows="3" name="new_area_note"></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_area">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Area">
</form>
```

The logic to process this new record is located in libhours/includes/_process.php

```
function cp_libhours_add_area() {
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

$new_area = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['new_area_name'] );
$new_url = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['new_area_url'] );
$new_note = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['new_area_note'] );

if($wpdb->insert($table_prefix . library_areas, array(
    'location' => $new_area,
    'displayOrder' => 0,
    'url' => $new_url,
    'note' => $new_note
    ))){
    $_SESSION['usermsg'] = '<p class="user-success">The new library area was added.</p>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['usermsg'] = '<p class="user-warning">There was an error adding the new library area. Please try again.</p>'; 
}
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
```

}

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'add_area') cp_libhours_add_area();
```

What I don't understand is: on submission of this form, the query is still executing cp_libhours_add_area as if I told the form to go to includes/_process.php.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some kind of javascript listener on the form submit event that is preventing the default action and redirecting it to the other url.

In Chrome developer tools if you inspect the form then look at event listeners filtered by the currently selected element you may be able to find out where this is happening and edit the javascript appropriately.

Comment: Close. I realized I was including the file on my plugin's main page not realizing that it would process regardless of what I set as the action. Thanks.